# Finding time of testing data in Sphinx train.

Tags: cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am training data via `pocketsphinx` and `sphinxtrain`. We can see our training data time in log file. like my current training data is shown as

```
Phase 5: Determine amount of training data, see if n_tied_states seems reasonable.
Estimated Total Hours Training: 1.00766111111111
```

After training, testing is done. for testing I have added 20 files. But I dont know what is length of these files. Finding it manually is a hard task as I am going to increase testing data.

So is there any `log file` or any other (than manual) way I can check my `testing data time`.

Answer (score 1):

I just found it, I am posting own answer so it may be helping for others

You can find it under `logdir/decode/dbname-1-1.log`
while dbname is your main folder name in my case logdir/decode/tester-1-1.log. 
Open this file and there will be a line

```
INFO: batch.c(778): TOTAL 81.24 seconds speech, 30.43 seconds CPU, 37.54 seconds wall
```

Here `TOTAL 81.24 seconds speech` is time of my testing audio data.